# SQL-Get highest record from group at another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have read several answers to related questions but none of them can be applied to this case.

I have a table `TableA` where several groups are listed, with their score:

```
GROUP|SCORE

Blue | 0      
Green| 0      
Red  | 0      
Orange| 0
```

On another table `TableB`, I have the parts of each group and their individual score (status), which can have three different values:

```
 - G (Good)
 - A (Average)
 - B (Bad)
```

So `tableB` is:

```
GROUP|PART|STATUS

Blue | 3H2| A  
Blue | 4NQ| G  
Blue | W9X| A  
Green| 65D| G  
Red  | 73F| B  
Red  | 91G| A
```

I need to Update the score on `TableA` in the following way:

- If the best status between the parts of the group is `G`, group score is 3
- If the best status between the parts of the group is `A`, group score is 2
- If the best status between the parts of the group is `B`, group score is 1

I have been a couple of days going around this and I can't find a solution. Thank you guys. Btw, I am using Access 2013.

Comment: First of all, you should have a table for the statuses containing the rank, so queries don't have to know themselves whether Status 'A' ranks higher then 'G' etc. Then you shouldn't store the score in tableA at all, because that would be redundant. As you say yourself: a group's status can be determined from tableB.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner to know which one rank is higher he could use `CASE expression`.

Comment: @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas: Yes, in every query. And never make typos. And once you want to introduce status 'H' for horrible, all queries must be changed. You could just as well use letters for the groups. G would be 'Green' and 'R' would be 'Red' and again you could use a `CASE` expression. See what I mean? :-)

Answer (score 2):

As I have already mentioned in the comments: Don't store the score redundantly; it is implicit in tableB. And to get your database straight introduce a status table:

```
STATUS   DESCRIPTION   SCORE
G        Good          3
A        Avarage       2
B        Bad           1
```

If you want to select the score for each color group use this query for instance:

```
select b.colorgroup, max(s.score) as maxscore
from tableb as b
join status as s on s.status = b.status
group by b.colorgroup;
```

Two alternative ways to write the same query:

```
select 
  colorgroup, 
  (
    select max(score)
    from status as s
    where s.status = b.status
  ) as maxscore
from tableb as b;
```

and

```
select b.colorgroup, s.maxscore
from tableb as b
join 
(
  select status, max(score) as maxscore
  from status
  group by status
) as s on s.status = b.status;
```

(BTW: I called your group `colorgroup` because `GROUP` is a reserved name in SQL.)

---

**UPDATE** You say you cannot add a table to the database. So you must evaluate the score in the query itself unfortunately. In standard SQL you would use `CASE WHEN`, which MS Access doesn't feature. MS Access provides `IIF` instead:

```
select 
  colorgroup, 
  max(iif(status = 'G', 3, iif(status = 'A', 2, 1))) as maxscore
from tableb
group by colorgroup;
```

If you even must use the column in tableA and store redundantly, use:

```
update tablea as a
set score =
(
  select 
    max(iif(status = 'G', 3, iif(status = 'A', 2, 1))) as maxscore
  from tableb as b
  where b.colorgroup = a.colorgroup
);
```

Comment: I agree, this would be the easiest and best way to do it, but due to irrelevant reasons I need to make it without modifying the tables or creating new ones. Any idea on how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Okay. The query is easy enough to write, but it's a pity you can't correct the sloppy database. Please see my update on how to aggregate conditional expressions in MS Access.

Comment: Thank you. However, when using your last query I am getting an error: "Operator must use an updatable query". Why? The error is quite surprising since the query doesn't look complicated

Comment: I forgot the table alias for tableb. Maybe that was the reason. If it wasn't, I have no clue as to what else MS Access might be complaining about.

Comment: It's not the alias... I found this on the internet: "Since Jet 4, all queries that have a join to a SQL statement that summarizes data will be non-updatable. You aren't using a JOIN, but the WHERE clause is exactly equivalent to a join, and thus, the Jet query optimizer treats it the same way it treats a join. [...]. BTW, it might have been updatable in Jet 3.5 (Access 97), as a whole lot of queries were updatable then that became non-updatable when upgraded to Jet 4." Interesting. Not exactly the same, but I believe this could be happening to me right now.

Comment: Yes, that may be. What a horrible DBMS. I am sorry you must use it. So the solution is probably outside SQL. Use VBA or any other programming language to do what you want in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you could do in following:

**QUERY**

```
update a
set a.SCORE = MaxSTATUS
from #a a
join  (select GROUP_, MAX(case when b.STATUS_ = 'G' then 3
                               when b.STATUS_ = 'A' then 2
                               when b.STATUS_ = 'B' then 1
                           end) MaxSTATUS
        from #b b
        group by GROUP_

) b ON a.GROUP_ = b.GROUP_

select * from #a
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #a
(
GROUP_ NVARCHAR(60),
SCORE INT
)
INSERT INTO #a VALUES
  ('Blue',0)
 ,('Green',0)
 ,('Red',0)
 ,('Orange',0)

CREATE TABLE #b
(
GROUP_ NVARCHAR(60),
PART NVARCHAR(60),
STATUS_ NVARCHAR(60),
)
INSERT INTO #b VALUES
  ('Blue','3H2','A')
 ,('Blue','4NQ','G')
 ,('Blue','W9X','A')
 ,('Green','65D','G')
 ,('Red','73F','B')
 ,('Red','91G','A')
```

**OUPUT**

```
GROUP_  SCORE
Blue    3
Green   3
Red     2
Orange  0
```

Comment: I have tried to adapt your answer to Access but I can't get it to work:

'UPDATE (A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT B.GROUP, MAX(

SWITCH(

B.STATUS = "G", "3",
B.STATUS = "A", "2",
B.STATUS = "B", "1")) as MaxSTATUS

FROM A, B

ON A.GROUP = B.GROUP

Group by GROUP) as c

SET A.SCORE = c.MaxSTATUS'

Could you give an access-friendly solution? I like your approach

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting in the comment, it's my first time writing here